# Lombok not generating getters/setters (with Luna or command line compile)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lombok

I'm trying to lombok for the first time.  I tried to follow directions as best as possible, but when I look at  my compiled classes (using a decompiler) they do not have any of the generated getters or setters.

My installation steps:

1. Downloaded lombok 1.14.8 and ran java -jar lombok.jar.  It added lombok to eclipse.  Restarted Eclipse (-clean the workspace too).  If I check my About Eclipse page, I see:

   "Lombok v1.14.8 "Branching Cobra" is installed. http://projectlombok.org/"
2. Added lombok to my pom.xml:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
       <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
       <version>1.14.8</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Maven->Update Project.  Project->Clean

My Lombok'ed java class:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

public class User extends BaseCouchDbDocument {

    public User() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Getter @Setter
    private String name;
}
```

When using the code completion in Eclipse, I see `User.getName()` and `User.setName()` appear.  However, if I try to use the getters or setters, I get a compile time error that no such method exists.  When I look at the generated .class file, I only see the following:

```
public class User extends BaseCouchDbDocument
{
  private String name;
}
```

Similarly, if I run `mvn compile` from the command line, I get the same class output.

What I find odd is that the `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations are removed, implying that there is some processing occurring on my files.  But the getters/setters aren't being generated.

Am I doing something wrong?  I'm using Java 7 on a Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After posting this, I ran across a bug report that indicated it was a problem with AspectJ.

Indeed, I am using AspectJ with my project, and it is causing conflicts with Lombok.  Removing AspectJ now shows properly generated setters/getters.

This obviously does not "resolve" the issue, but at least points me in the right direction.  I [created another issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25903686/827480) to track this specific problem.

Hopefully this can help someone else in the future as well.